# why internet explorer phone enlarges elements?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, mobile, responsive-design

I am working on responsivizing a website and on chrome for example all is working as expected. I use the device mode to emulate the responsive version of the website. However, when i'm using internet explorer everything is quite bigger and pictures appear pixelated like they would when you stretch them.

I tried using the bicubic css property thing but no dice. Also the zoom option is at 100% (heard some other people had theirs zoomed in).

This is how the code for culprit items would look like

**HTML**

```
<div id="category-contents">
    <div class="cell-wrapper">
        <div class="cell-wrapper-inside">
            <a href="http://www.theperfecturn.com/small-cross-cremation-jewelry-c-481.html" class="image product-thumb-image" style="background: url('images/categories/sm/481.smallcrosscremat_sm.jpg') 2px 2px no-repeat;"><img src="http://cdn.perfectmemorials.com/categories_layout/photo-frame.png" alt="Small Cross Cremation Jewelry" title=" Small Cross Cremation Jewelry " width="124" height="124"> </a>

            <a href="http://www.theperfecturn.com/small-cross-cremation-jewelry-c-481.html" class="title">Small Cross Cremation Jewelry</a>

            <div class="button-wrapper"><a href="http://www.theperfecturn.com/small-cross-cremation-jewelry-c-481.html"><img src="http://cdn.perfectmemorials.com/categories_layout/button-category.gif" class="category" alt="View Small Cross Cremation Jewelry Category"></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#category-contents{
    overflow: hidden;
}    

#category-contents .cell-wrapper,
#results-products .cell-wrapper{
    box-sizing: border-box;

    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
}

#category-contents .cell-wrapper .title{    
    height: 65px;
}

#results-products .cell-wrapper .title{

}

#category-contents .cell-wrapper .cell-wrapper-inside,
#results-products .cell-wrapper .cell-wrapper-inside{
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}

#category-contents .cell-wrapper .button-wrapper,
#results-products .cell-wrapper .button-wrapper{
    position: static;
    width: auto;
}

.cell-wrapper .button-wrapper .product{
    float: none !important;

}

.cell-wrapper .button-wrapper .volume{
    float: none !important;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
}
```

http://puu.sh/hKEHh/3ceb0a9168.jpg <- how it looks on chrome
http://puu.sh/hKEP6/3f8f2aad40.jpg <- how it looks on ie

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to zero out the padding and margin for the body

so add to your css

```
body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

It is hard to see exactly what is happening without access to the actually files